# Можно ли в MySQL установить права на прцедуры

Tags: mysql

Можно ли в MySQL установить права для пользователя таким образом, что бы он не мог выполнять запросы на insert, update, delete, но мог вызывать хранимые процедуры, выполняющие такие запросы. Если можно, то как?

Comment: При создании процедуры можно указать, что она будет выполняться с правами создателя, а не исполнителя. См. `SQL SECURITY DEFINER`.

Comment: И как? доказали?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Синтаксис запроса для отмены привилегий пользователя:

```
REVOKE privilege ON object FROM username
```

где privilege - это [тип привилегии](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/GRANT.html) (в вашем случае - INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).

Если вдруг захотите установить привилегию обратно:

```
GRANT privilege ON object TO username
```

Обновить привилегии можно с помощью `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`

При [создании процедуры](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) необходимо указать, с какими правами она будет выполняться:

- INVOKER - скрипт выполняется с правами пользователя , который её
  вызвал,
- DEFINER - скрипт выполняется с правами пользователя указанного в
  CREATE DEFINER.